# Unable to deploy debezium mysql connector using Confluent docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry, debezium

I trying to run a docker image of confluent to intiate connect service with Debezium MYSQL connector , but failed to get the loaded class after running the docker.

**Docker Command**

```
docker run -d \
    --name=kafka-connect \
    --net=host \
    -e CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="b-2.<bootstrap_server>.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092,b-3.<bootstrap_server>.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092,b-1.<bootstrap_server>.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092" \
    -e CONNECT_REST_PORT=8083 \
    -e CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH="/usr/share/java,/tmp/connectors" \
    -e CONNECT_GROUP_ID="quickstart" \
    -e CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC="quick-config" \
    -e CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC="quick-offsets" \
    -e CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC="quick-status" \
    -e CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
    -e CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
    -e CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
    -e CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER="org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter" \
    -e CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME="ec2-<public_ip>.compute-1.amazonaws.com" \
    -v /opt/connectors:/tmp/connectors \
    confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:3.1.2
```

**My Instance directory files used in the volume (-v) is as below:**

```
ubuntu@ip-<hostname>:/opt/connectors$ ls
debezium-connect-jdbc
```

**Below command to test whether Debezium Mysql driver class loaded or not**

```
curl -s http://ec2-<public_ip>.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8083/connector-plugins | jq .
```

**After running the above command I donot see the class for Debezium Mysql connector as mentioned below**

```
io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is too old Kafka Connect version: `confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:3.1.2` [ships](https://docs.confluent.io/3.1.2/release-notes.html#apache-kafka-0-10-1-1) with 0.10.1.1 version, but [Classloading Isolation in Connect](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-146+-+Classloading+Isolation+in+Connect) was implemented only in 0.11.0.

Please use newer [images](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/image-reference.html).